# Bitwise shift operator and file pointer

Tags: c, file, pointers, bit-manipulation, shift

Can you please explain why, whenever I call this function, the file pointer is shifted?
How does this piece of code work?
...

```
static long fget32le(FILE* fp)
{
    long answer;
    answer = fgetc(fp);
    answer |= (fgetc(fp) << 8);
    answer |= (fgetc(fp) << 16);
    answer |= (fgetc(fp) << 24);
    /* check for negative */
    if (answer & 0x80000000)
        answer |= ((-1) << 31);
    return answer;
}
```

...

Try this simple example by your own. Try to comment fget32le(file) functions and check the behavior of fread. Then try to run the same with fget32le(file) enabled: the behaviour of fread changes as it starts reading after a 64 bits offset.

```
pBitmap loadBmp(const char* fileIn) 
{
    FILE* file = fopen(fileIn, "rb");
    if (!file) {
        printf("Unable to load file\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    fget32le(file);
    fget32le(file);

    unsigned char bmpHeader[54];
    fread(bmpHeader, 1, 54, file);

    if (bmpHeader[0] != 'B' || bmpHeader[1] != 'M') {
        printf("The loaded file is not a valid Bitmap\n");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    int width = *(int*)&bmpHeader[18];
    int height = *(int*)&bmpHeader[22];
```

Comment: It's not the file pointer that gets shifted, it's the value returned by `fgetc`. The function is reading a 32-bit little endian integer from the file, one byte at a time, and assembling it into a `long` with bitshift and OR.

Comment: When I declare FILE *file = fopen(.... and after that I call fget32le twice, the behavior looks like this: the starting address of *file is: 0x0000029a82642fe0, then it becomes 0x0000029a8264e924 and then 0x0000029a8264e928. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: @Marco that doesn't have anything to do with the program you show though. Post a [mre]. You are most probably observing different addresses because the value is being passed around in different functions and therefore is copied on the stack. Not a problem at all, completely normal.

Comment: @Marco edit your question to add code, don't post it in a comment. (if the code is relevant to the question obviously)

Comment: I did it, please check my edited question

Comment: @Marco read my edited answer

Comment: Are you asking why `fread` reads different bits of the file depending on how many characters you first read using `fgetc` ?

Comment: Please check my example and try to reproduce it by your own. The function aims to read .bmp file and try to check whether its format is valid or not by reading the first two bytes. If you run the same piece of code with the fget32le functions commented it does work, If you run it with the 2 functions enabled it doesen't as it seems the fp is shifted. Please check it out via the visual studio watcher by enabling the place holder.

Comment: @Marco is it so hard to understand that if you read 8 bytes, the next read will be from the 9th byte? I think it is logical

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file pointer is not being shifted, only the character read.

The negative check should be

```
if(answer < 0)
```

This line invokes undefined behavior

```
answer |= ((-1) << 31);
```

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated
> bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of
> the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value
> representable in the result type. **If E1 has a signed type and
> nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type,
> then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is
> undefined.**

> file is: 0x0000029a82642fe0, then it becomes 0x0000029a8264e924 and
> then 0x0000029a8264e928. This is why I'm asking.

This function cannot change the pointer passed as it is local to the `fget32le` function. Your observation is wrong or something else (which you did not show us) is changing the pointer.

> Try this simple example by your own. Try to comment fget32le(file)
> functions and check the behavior of fread. Then try to run the same
> with fget32le(file) enabled: the behaviour of fread changes as it
> starts reading after a 64 bits offset.

It is because you have already read 8 bytes, so the file will be read by `fread` from the 9th byte.

If you want to start again from the beginning you need to :

```
    fget32le(file);
    fget32le(file);

    /* ... */
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fread(bmpHeader, 1, 54, file);
```